# When does it make sense for multiple consumers from the same consumer group to read from the same partition?

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-eventhub

I'm learning event hubs concept in Azure event hubs and kafka.

A consumer group can have 1 or more consumers. And one or more consumers from a consumer group can read 1 or more partitions.

1 consumer from the consumer group should ideally consume from 1 Partition.

I'm trying to understand in what scenario does it make sense for multiple consumers from the same consumer group to read from the same partition?

Comment: Are you running a Kafka client or an AMQP client? Consumer context is a little different between both.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to understand in what scenario does it make sense for multiple consumers from the same consumer group to read from the same partition?

I can think of none. If you use the official SDKs by using an event processor for example, it isn't even possible since each consumer locks a single partition, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-processor-balance-partition-load#partition-ownership-tracking).

> 1 consumer from the consumer group should ideally consume from 1 Partition.

That is correct. When using the SDK a consumer in a consumer group takes a lock on the partition it is reading from. If multiple consumers in the same consumer group want to read from the same partition they will have to compete to get the lock, which is not efficient.

Comment: "will have to compete to get the lock" - Kafka doesn't even allow that to happen

Comment: What is the way to make it queue versus pubsub kind of model?

Comment: @variable there is no way to make it a queue, if you want a proper queue, use a queue service like azure service bus.